# Markdown list does not indent using octopress

Tags: markdown, octopress

I am using octopress to write a blog. Now I encounter a problem. When I use the asterisk * or the hyphen - to define a list, the rendered list does not indent. So now the content of the list are aligned with other texts, while the points that lead the list are standing out, which makes the blog ugly.

It should look like this:

Other text

- list1
- list2

Now it looks like this(without the asterisk):

*****Other text

- list1
- list2

I think the snapshot below is more illustrative:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out according to someone'e blog.
In octopress/sass/custom/layout.css 
turn

```
//$indented-lists: true;
```

into

```
$indented-lists: true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to fix the CSS. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet, because I don't know how T=T.